# Problems with angle and target coordinates

Tags: python, math, pygame

When player shoots `Bullet` class is being initialized.

```
class Bullet(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y, tx, ty, angle):
        ...
        self.tx, self.ty = tx, ty
        # Here's the problematic part
        self.tx += random.uniform(-15, 15)
        self.ty += random.uniform(-15, 15)

        self.angle = get_angle(x, y, self.tx, self.ty)
        ...
        self.velx, self.vely = get_vel(self.angle, 18)

def get_angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    rise = y1 - y2
    run = x1 - x2
    angle = math.atan2(run, rise)
    angle = angle / (math.pi / 180)
    return angle

def get_vel(angle, offset):
   return (math.sin(angle * (math.pi / 180)) * offset, math.cos(angle * (math.pi / 180)) * offset)
```

When distance between `x` and `tx` or `y` and `ty` is small `angle` is getting weird.
Sometimes bullets even go the opposite direction.

How do I fix that?

Comment: By using a better constraint than `random.uniform()`.

Comment: You're right, randint would be better. But it doesn't really matter. The problem is with the number.

Comment: It does matter. Your current constraint is allowing it to have these strange trajectories.

Comment: The problem is with number. For example: tx is 50, x is 20, random number is 14.62. So tx is 64.62 now. The random number is too big. However, if I make it smaller trajectory will be too accurate.

Comment: I suggest making your modifications to `tx` and `ty` proportional to the difference between `x` and `tx`, e.g. +/-10%, rather than a fixed value. That will make sure you go roughly in the right direction even if you start close to the target point. Another idea might be to not fudge the `tx` and `ty` values at all, but to adjust the calculated angle by some small amount directly.

Comment: It tried to adjust angle before. It worked fine untill I added tx and ty. Those are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scale the constraint based on distance, up to a maximum value. It makes no sense for the aim point to be further in distance from the target than the shooter.